# Generate a Reference number from a Post ID in PHP

Tags: php

I want to generate a Reference number that users can use to search or save when they want to send it to the agent, or return to a site.

What I have is this -> what I want:

```
 '45'     ->  REF4903295762
 '421'    ->  REF3425436346
 '1250'   ->  REF4695039476
```

Adding the 'REF' string is not a issue, but generating even length numbers and/or letters from a ID and having it decodable back is the important bit.

P.S. Something in line with what URL shorteners do.

Comment: To the P.S.: I assume shorteners just store a key-value tuple in their database, with the key as the shortstring and the value as the long...
But that doesnt help you.

Comment: Why not to store reference number in database? You can generate it based on the current timestamp.

Comment: What's wrong with just left-padding with `0`s?

Comment: Don't really want to store anything extra in the DB, want PHP to decode it on the fly if you search for "REF#########", and decoding the string from a timestamp, will give me back the timestamp back which isn't something I want to search upon. `REF45` is the easy answer but gives away the post ID, plus the system might contain Ref's from other sites (ie. property sites)

Answer (score 0):

Well... normally the numbers after REF **are** the ID. But, if you want it random, you create another column called "Ref". You create a random number

```
$string = rand(0, 9999999);
```

Then you use MySQL to check that it's not used, so like

```
$used = true;
while($used)
{
    $string = rand(0, 9999999);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `REF`='$string'");
    if(!mysql_num_rows($query))
    {
        $used = false;
    }
}
```

And then you insert it after that. And then you can just look up by that column in the future. Check if that's how you use mysql_num_rows though, I'm not sure if you need to use msyql_fetch_array before it or not

Comment: What about when I have 9999998 records? This code will loop for a *very* long time before it finds the last spare ID. This is exactly why consecutive IDs are a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, I know ,that's why I it's usual REF{ID}, instead of a random number, like I started off the post with. Sometimes even knowing the wrong answer can help you learn, in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class/CI_Library I created.

```
<?php
class Xref{
    private $key = 24040410;//secret key - change to your own key (int only)[length = 8]
    private $limit = 67000000;//num limit [do not change]

    function encrypt($num){
        if($num > $this->limit){
            return false;
        }else{
            $binaryString = $this->toBinaryString($num);
            $reversedBinaryString = $this->reverseString($binaryString);
            $reversedBinaryInt = bindec($reversedBinaryString);
            $xor = $this->key ^ $reversedBinaryInt;
            return str_pad($xor, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
    }
    function decrypt($str){
        $xor = $this->key ^ intval($str);

        return bindec($this->reverseString($this->toBinaryString($xor)));
    }

    private function toBinaryString($num){
        return str_pad(decbin($num), 26, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    private function reverseString($str){
        return strrev($str);
    }
}
?>
```

Just use `encrypt($ID)` to convert into a "random-like" numbers, and `decrypt($str)` to get the ID back.

Comment: I'm gonna test this and let you know what I find. Thanks.